# Why use One-To-One instead of inherit User class in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

So I want to be able to have Organizations and Customers which are users, which have some specific attributes. Everywhere I see, they use One-To-One mapping to the User class like this:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, primary_key=True)
    tenant=models.ForeignKey(Tenant, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    organization_name=models.CharField(max_length=100, default="No Organization name set")
    phone_number=models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=None)
    description=models.TextField(max_length=None, default="No Description set")
    is_terms_and_conditions_agreed=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status=models.IntegerField(choices=status_choices, default= PENDING)
```

which works fine for me, but this works as well:

```
class Organization(User):
    tenant=models.ForeignKey(Tenant, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    organization_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    alt_number=models.PositiveBigIntegerField()
    description=models.TextField(max_length=None)
    is_terms_and_conditions_agreed=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status=models.IntegerField(choices=status_choices, default= PENDING)
```

But I cannot find a reference for inheriting User class this way without making it a proxy and making a manager. So my question is, why do we prefer the One-To-One method?

Comment: If you use inheritance like in the second example, Django simply construct such `OneToOneField` itself.

Comment: But inheritance in Django (and any other ORM) is often *not* a good idea. Relational databases simply do not work very well with inheritance: it will introduce a lot of extra querying, making foreign key constraints less useful, etc.

Comment: Alright, I will go with One-To-One fields then. Thanks!